# Doesn't work route model binding in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My `route`:

```php
Route::get('/users/{user}', function(App\Models\User $user) {
  dd($user);
});
```

where `{user}` - id of model. A user with this name is in the database.

I check so:

```php
Route::put('/users/{user}', function(int $id) {
  dd(App\Models\User::find($id)->toArray());
});
```

I tried to bind in `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
  return App\Models\User::where('id', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

**UPDATE**

When binding, I get an empty instance

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: your 1st code what error your getting ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul No, why should I get an error?

Comment: so code is working ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Returns an empty instance. And there should be user data.

Comment: have you changed your primary key for user model ? if yes then you need to define the primary key in the `App\Models\Users.php`

Comment: I'm updating the question

Answer (score 0):

its been awhile, if anyone still need it try route:clear